# Transitivity of uncorrelated random variables?

Tags: statistics

Suppose $cov(X,Y)=0\;$ and $\;cov(Y,M)=0$. Does this imply $cov(X,M)=0\;$, if all distinct RV are normal?

Comment: *Individually* normal doesn't help.

Comment: Calling the third random variable M instead of Z is quite odd. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 5):

In general, no. Take $X = M$ ;)

It also does not hold if $(X,Y,Z)$ follow a Multivariate Normal $(\mu,\Sigma)$.

Necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix to be a covariance matrix $(\Sigma)$ are presented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Which_matrices_are_covariance_matrices.3F). A matrix is a covariance matrix if and only if it is positive semi-definite.

Hence, take

$$\Sigma =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

and observe that $Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X,Z) = 0$ but $Cov(Y,Z)=1$.

Comment: +1: The question has changed so this becomes "Take $X=M$"